# C# Injecting ConfigurationManager within unit tests

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing

I've searched around and no answers have worked for me. I have 2 ASP.NET projects, one of them being my project, the other being a project containing unit tests.

```
# Projects
Project.Core
    ...
    secretConnectionStrings.config
    Web.config

Project.Tests
```

In `Project.Core`, I have a method that requests both a connection string (from `secretConnectionStrings.config` and an app setting from the web.config file. Executing on it's own, the correct values are pulled from both of these config files. However, I want to test this within my unit test.

My test looks like this (within `Project.Tests`):

```
[TestClass]
public class TestUserController
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Post_ShouldReturnNewUser()
    {
        var controller = new UserController();

        var result = controller.Post() as User;
        Assert.AreNotEqual(result, null);
    }
}
```

The line it bombs out on is this

```
string cacheConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RedisCache"].ConnectionString;
```

**System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

I've tried adding `web.config` and `secretConnectionStrings.config` as a link in my `Project.Tests` solution. That hasn't worked, and I do not want to interface to my web.config (I want the values as they are saved in `Project.Core`). Is there a solution where I can pull values from `Project.Core`'s web.config into my unit test?

Comment: Your unit test is in separate project. You have to add connection string in that project.

Comment: Is there not a way to resort to that? I don't want to introduce another thing that can fail by maintaining 2 sets of config files for 2 projects

Comment: Have you considered creating a wrapper class for ConfigurationManager, using the wrapper in your real code and then fake the wrapper in the unit tests?

Comment: I don't want to mock the data in the config files, I would like to inject it.

Comment: @Zac, Test project is not  a web project you need to have `app.config` with the app settings copied over.

Comment: Is it possible to copy the web.config to the test project, and inject its contents into app.config from the pre/post-build events within the test project?

Comment: @Zac way too much work for what it is worth. I get around that by having a very slim config file and putting things like app setting and connection strings in external config files and have the app/web config file link to those config files. in the project and have the external config files and content and copy to output folder.

Comment: @Nkosi So you have external config files that you link to from your main and test projects? You then set this external config file to "Copy to output directory" to yes?

Comment: @Zac yep that is how I do it but with a slight twist. Lets say I have some common config that remains the same whether in test, live or dev. I have that in the main config file be it web or app. On my dev machine I have external config file with connection string to my dev db and have that file as not copy. on my live environment i have the same config file be it web or app with its own version of external configs. when deploying, the main config will copy but the external configs are not touched. that way I don't have to make any changes when moving between environments.

Comment: I've done it the other way around for other projects with no problems either.

Comment: Such a hacky way, you'd think this would be easier and more integrated.. I can try this a go

Comment: You have to provide configuration for test projects. It should be standard flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project containing the unit tests will need its own config file for the ConfigurationManager to pull in the connection strings. The best way to set this up *and* the keep only 1 copy of the config file is to add the same file into each project that needs it, but add it as a linked file:

[image: Add Linked File]

Don't forget to set the file properties so that it deploys with the executable code:
[image: Build Action]

And add it as a deployment item to your test fixture(s):

```
[TestClass]
[DeploymentItem(@"db.config")]
public class MyTestFixture { ... }
```

Now, if you want to have centralized connection strings in two differently-named config files (`app.config` & `web.config`), then you can place them in a third file `db.config` and import that file into each of the other config files:

**db.config**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="testDb" connectionString="data source=(localdb)\v11.0;..."
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**app.config / web.config**

```
<connectionStrings configSource="db.config" />
```

Make sure to set Copy To Output Directory for the imported config files in addition to your app.config or web.config and add them as deployment items to the test fixture with the attribute.

Comment: Is there a way to put the contents of this config file in `app.config`? The test project has that as it's config file, if the linked file is named `web.config`, will the changes properly pick up?

Comment: I've followed your example and am getting the same error. I believe it is because the unit tests are looking for `app.config` and I cannot use a different name of the config file

Comment: The answer has been updated to address the different named config files.